# Creating an automation in Google Spreadsheets to copy from a blank file and rename it based on a table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What i'm trying to do is to automate a sheet to copy a file from a blank file and rename it based on values on a table. For example, what i want to achieve is to create an automation in which I can create a copy of the blank document, name it with the Agent ID, and if possible, send it to the respective email on the same table. Is this possible within Google spreadsheets? I was trying to do Macros, but I cannot find the way to do it.

[This is what the sheet would look like (sample doc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0lAT.png)

Comment: It definitely is possible with Apps Script. Have you tried coding anything so far that you can share ?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should be close:

```
function copyAndSend() {
  const tfid='Temporary Folder Id';
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  const agids=sh.getRange(4,2,sh.getLastRow()-3,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  const emails=sh.getRange(6,2,sh.getLastRow()-3,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  const url=sh.getRange('C2').getValue()
  const id=url.slice(url.indexOf('/d/')+3,url.indexOf('/edit'));
  const file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  const folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  agids.forEach(function(id,i){
    let f=file.makeCopy(id, folder);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emails[i], 'File Copy', '', {attachments:[f]});
  });
}
```